# Rails - has_many with different column names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

I have a data model - `SeasonTeams` with the following relation:

`has_many :linked_team_constraints, class_name: 'LinkedTeamConstraints', dependent: :destroy`

Then I have the `LinkedTeamConstraints` model as follows:

`belongs_to :season_team, primary_key: :_id`

Now when I call `destroy` on the `SeasonTeam` - thereby destroying the `LinkedTeamConstraint` - I get error `column linked_team_constraints.season_team_id does not exist`. I *do* have two OTHER columns labeled `season_team_id_1` and `season_team_id_2`. How can I establish a has_many relationship such that `linked_team_constraints.season_team_id_1` or `..._id_2` is queried instead of `...season_team_id`.

Would it be something like:

`has_many :linked_team_constraints... {where("_id == ?", linked_team_constraints.season_team_id_1 || linked_team_constraints.season_team_id_2)}`?

Comment: Try this   belongs_to :season_team, :foreign_key => "season_team_id"

Comment: @AnassAnas that won't work because `season_team_id` isn't a column on `linked_team_constraints`

Comment: ok then add it or use season_team_id_1 instead of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `foreign_key` for your relations and have separate relation for each key. Like:

```
has_many :linked_team_1_constraints, class_name: 'LinkedTeamConstraints', foreign_key: :season_team_id_1, dependent: :destroy   
has_many :linked_team_2_constraints, class_name: 'LinkedTeamConstraints', foreign_key: :season_team_id_2, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: So this _technically_ works (all my unit/function tests pass), but is it possible to have multiple foreign keys on a single relation?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As "solution", you can define method `linked_team_constraints` and just use `where` clause. `LinkedTeamConstraints.where('season_team_id_1 = ? OR season_team_id_2 = ?', _id)`.